# Tensorflow only loading a little amount of the dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

```
105385/105398 - 99.99%
105386/105398 - 99.99%
105387/105398 - 99.99%
105388/105398 - 99.99%
105389/105398 - 99.99%
105390/105398 - 99.99%
105391/105398 - 99.99%
105392/105398 - 99.99%
2020-06-24 13:28:03.026755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.246801: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.493GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2020-06-24 13:28:03.293755: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.468178: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.536838: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.578693: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.658591: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.738893: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.862886: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:03.872659: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-06-24 13:28:03.881362: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-06-24 13:28:03.963845: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1f9b9fc2780 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-24 13:28:03.973050: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-06-24 13:28:03.982159: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1561] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.493GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2020-06-24 13:28:04.007828: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_101.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.023283: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.029813: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.044668: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.056612: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusolver64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.062884: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_10.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.078071: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cudnn64_7.dll
2020-06-24 13:28:04.092216: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1703] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2020-06-24 13:28:06.133816: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1102] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2020-06-24 13:28:06.144668: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1108]      0
2020-06-24 13:28:06.151187: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1121] 0:   N
 -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2020-06-24 13:28:06.190853: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x1f9c88d7080 initialized for platform CUDA (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-06-24 13:28:06.207978: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 1050, Compute Capability 6.1
2020-06-24 13:28:43.665652: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:44] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_10.dll
3294/3294 [==============================] - 15s 5ms/step - loss: 3.7319 - accuracy: 0.0249
```

I have a total of 10592 images converted to numpy array of bitmaps through this code below

```
for x in train_data.category.tolist():
if x < 10:
  x = "0" + str(x)
  path = os.path.join(train_DATADIR,x)
else:
  x = str(x)
  path = os.path.join(train_DATADIR,x)
img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,str(train_data.filename[idx])), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
new_array = cv2.resize(img_array,(img_size,img_size))
train_images.append(new_array)
# plt.imshow(img_array,cmap="gray")
# plt.title(x)
# plt.xlabel(train_data.filename[idx])
# plt.show()
idx += 1
print(f'{idx}/105398 - {idx/105398:.2f}%')
```

but in the end, tensorflow only process 3294 images.
Anyone what's wrong with it?

I did noticed that when tensorflow is running, CPU usage is nearly 100% but GPU is sitting around ~15%

Below is my code for creating the model.

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(80, 80)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(42)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=1)
```

Comment: Hello, could you please give some information about batch size parameter that you are using? 3294 gives you information about number of steps on each epoch. Its values depends of number of images that will be taken into each step to train your network.

Comment: Well I updated the OP with my code for creating the model, not quite sure what is batch size argument though...

Comment: Could you please try to modify your code with ``` model.fit(train_images, train_labels, batch_size, epochs=1) ``` You can also use some predefined structure from here: https://keras.io/examples/cifar10_cnn/